# How to cast from int to byte, then use a bitshift operator

Tags: java, casting, colors, binary, bit-shift

Why does the following not work? I cast an int to a byte, then shift the bits over by 7. I don't see any problems there.

However, I get the error message "possible loss of precision... required: byte; found: int"

`pixels` is an array of bytes, `c` is a Color object, `iter` is an integer.

```
pixels[iter++] = ((byte) c.getRed()) << 7;
pixels[iter++] = ((byte) c.getGreen()) << 7;
pixels[iter++] = ((byte) c.getBlue()) << 7;
```

Comment: How about: `(byte)(c.getRed() << 7);`?

Answer (score 3):

In Java, the shift operators return an `int` value, even if the quantity being shifted is a `byte`. You need to wrap the cast to `byte` around the entire expression:

```
pixels[iter++] = (byte) (c.getRed() << 7);
pixels[iter++] = (byte) (c.getGreen() << 7);
pixels[iter++] = (byte) (c.getBlue() << 7);
```

Comment: Thanks, I had a feeling it had something to with the operator itself.

Comment: You have an extra parens btw - should be (c.getRed() << 7);

Comment: @user1796994 - thanks; parens now fixed. Perils of cut-and-paste without a syntax checker. :)