# Java bit shift (lsh) << - error in Java?

Tags: java, bit-manipulation, bit-shift

I have an expression:

```
short w = (short) ((byte) dana) << x);
...
String.format ("%04X", w);
```

if they includes:

`dana = (byte) 0x88;`
and
`int x = 5;`

I receive 0xF100

instead of 0x1100

What can I do to make it properly!

Comment: You can perform a bitwise and (`&`) operation to mask the higher bits.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is in the first cast:

```
(byte) dana
```

`dana` is converted to `byte`, so then when it is later used in expression it needs to be widened back to `int` and this is done with sign-extension. If number is negative all higher bits are set to 1 to keep its value in 2-complement.

Use bitmask instead:

```
short w = (short) ((dana & 0xff) << x);
```

Perhaps it would be even better to avoid using `short` as well, since java does all arithmetics on `int` anyway.

Comment: Ok, it works! Thank You! But what, if I should make XOR operation on short?  ie: short compute; compute ^=w;  ???? compute = compute & 0xFFFF?

Comment: @blackmoon, I don't really understand. Using XOR shouldn't usually mess with higher bits. If you want to widen `short` to `int` with no sign extension than `& 0xFFFF` is a good choice. But when assigning to `short` it is rather pointless.

Comment: i should calculate a CRC ... in C++ : `short CalcCrc(char *str,int len)
{
short crc=0;
for(int i=0;i<len;i++)
crc ^= (short)((unsigned char)str[i]) << (i%9);
return crc;
}`  but in Java it is't allways that same (if i use this same string)

Comment: @blackmoon, I think replacing `(unsigned char)` with `0xff &` should be enough. In this case changing `short crc` to `int` and removing `(short)` shouldn't change much either, as you never set high bits anyway.

Answer (score 1):

Check this answer: [How to cast from int to byte, then use a bitshift operator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16782412/how-to-cast-from-int-to-byte-then-use-a-bitshift-operator)

You begin with (extension sign)

```
  1111 1111 1111 1111 1111 1111 1000 1000
```

And do the shift

```
  1111 1111 1111 1111 1111 0001 0000 0000
```

As you cast to short, you end with

```
  1111 0001 0000 0000
```

Which is the result that you get.

The solution is using a wider value (at least `short`), so it will not be negative. zch's answer is also valid.

Answer (score -1):

You can perform a bitwise and (&) operation to mask the higher bits. For instance:

```
w &= 0x1fff;
```

The issue is that when one converts the data to a byte, the sign bit is activated and arithmetic operations are performed instead of logical ones. By using an nd operation, the higher bits are cut off. Or you can postpone conversions and do it as a postprocessing.

One sometimes can also use the arithmetic shifts

Comment: You are not explaining a solution, but a patch. Doing `w = 0x1100` also gives the expected result, but it is not a solution either.

Comment: What is "arithmetic shifts"? `<<` and `>>` are *signed shifts* and `>>>` is *unsigned shifts* (and only works in the opposite direction, there is no `<<<`)

Comment: Some languages provide rotations, which some people classify as arithmetic shifts as well. I know the scope is Java, but if one wants to learn programming, he should see the large picture, not simply an implementation of a programming language...